# Recommended way to edit dynamic JSON objects?

Tags: admin-on-rest

Is there a input field I can use to let the user edit dynamic JSON (large nested object without fixed schema)?
Or do I need to write my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to implement your own component for that